# using visual studio DockerfileRunArguments parameter within launchsettings.json

Tags: docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure-container-apps

I am creating container app than uses a Docker container.

> ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Staging"

I figured I could reference this docker environment file with --env-file dockerfile-staging.conf

```
"Docker": {
  "commandName": "Docker",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
  "DockerfileRunArguments": "--env-file dockerfile-staging.conf",
  "publishAllPorts": true,
  "useSSL": true
}
```

The environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is not set and by default is Development.

I do not see any errors.

If I use the following the aspnetcore environment variable is set as Staging correctly.

**Any Idea why may be wrong?**

```
"DockerfileRunArguments": "-e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--env-file dockerfile-staging.conf` isn't working b/c VS is passing `-e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` as part of the `docker run` and docker prioritizes the value from the command line over that in the env file. Using -e is working for the same reason.

As an alternative you can use:

```
"Docker": {
  "commandName": "Docker",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
  "publishAllPorts": true,
  "useSSL": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
  }
}
```

The values in `environmentVariables` are set for just the process, so even if you don't see the value in the container tools window, you will see it in your process.

Comment: Is it possible to see the full command line that vs.net is using to start the container ?

Comment: Yes, if you go to the Container tools pane of the output window the command is logged there